# Multiplication and division with counters while also formatting

Tags: macros, formatting, tex-core, counters, calculations

See the code that follows.

The user gives some pairs of numbers. Each time they happen also to be displayed.

Finally they are added up in a specific way.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\def\Result...

\newcount{\A}\A=0

\newcount{\B}\B=0

\newcount{\C}\C=0

\def\XYZ{#1,#2}{\textbf{#1}---\textbf{#2}\A=#1\B=#2\multiply\A by 100\advance\C by \A\advance\C by \B}

\begin{document}
\XYZ{4,30}

\XYZ{7,30}

\XYZ{9,40}

%\Result

\end{document}
```

This kind of code prevents the document from ever compiling.

1. What is wrong with it? How can it be fixed?
2. Can it be rewritten using `\newcounter`, `\setcounter`, `\countainedwithin*`, and other LaTeX methods? I am interested in knowing both the correct TeX and LaTeX methods to achieve the result.
3. How does one write a macro `\Result` that takes \C and divides by 100 and if the result is three digits EFG, writes \textbf{E},\textbf{FG}, and if the result is four digits EFGH, writes \textbf{EF},\textbf{GH} instead?
4. In case it has fewer than three digits, to add 0 for G or 00 for FG and use the three digit case.

I am looking for something that does not involve the calc package by the way. A result rounded to the nearest FG or GH in \Result is also fine.

For the `\Result`

```
\def\Result{\divide\C by 100\textbf{\the\C}}
```

is working now - but now sure how to handle rounding up to nearest H in the EF.GH.

If it did work, not sure how to handle the fractional part and cut off to at most two digits on each side of a dividing marker.

Comment: It does not combine independent of what \Result is defined as being. So the first problem is in the counters.

Comment: Also the issue may be in using {#1,#2} in the definition. However it is not ideal to have to enter pairs by \XYZ{X,Y.} in the use document, if doing something like \def\XYZ#1,#2.{...

Comment: `\newcount{\A}\B=0` gives an error that `\B` isn't defined. This is a typo for `\A`

Comment: Type fixed - that was a typo in my M\strikethrough{W}E.

Comment: `\def\XYZ{#1,#2}` is a syntax x error.

Comment: for part 3 of your question `\C` / 100 in this example is 21 so neither three nor 4 digits, what output do you want in this case?

Comment: Good point - edited the question above.

Comment: Usual syntax for `\newcount` is to give the argument without braces (it's a plain TeX macro). Not that it doesn't work with the braces, but I find it a bit strange (if you were to play this game with primitives such as `\let` or `\ifx`, you'd get bitten).

Comment: Ty - that fixed it. @frougon Will keep in mind that braces cannot be used. Should \relax sometimes be used if separation needed and all one line?
Edited the question - now remains only figure out how to cut off something like 25.7888, round up to nearest H in EF.GH. Currently rounds down to nearest EF.

Comment: This has no relation to this question as far as I can see... If it's for printing, you can use `siunitx` with `\usepackage[round-mode=places, round-precision=2]{siunitx}` and `\num{25.7888}`. Another technique for printing is to use `\pgfmathprintnumber`. If it's not for printing but as input for further calculi, that's a wholly different question, please ask it in a separate one.

Answer (score 2):

It's not at all clear what calculation or output you want so I fixed the syntax errors, left the calculation, then made it typeset the values of A B and C

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%\def\Result...

\newcount{\A}\A=0

\newcount{\B}\B=0

\newcount{\C}\C=0

\def\XYZ#1{\XYZa#1\relax}
\def\XYZa#1,#2\relax{\textbf{#1}:\textbf{#2}%
\A=#1\relax
\B=#2\relax
\multiply\A by 100\relax
\advance\C by \A
\advance\C by \B
[\the\A,\the\B,\the\C]%
}

\begin{document}
\XYZ{4,30}

\XYZ{7,30}

\XYZ{9,40}

%\Result

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see, `\relax` is the "magic" in these cases.

Comment: @GottfriedWilliam not really: mostly they are not needed but you had not terminated any of the assignments `\A=#1` would set `\A` to be #1 followed by whatever digits the following tokens expand to, you were just lucky that the following tokens don't expand to digits here. Using `\relax` makes the end of the assignment explicit. The main change is fixing the `\def` syntax and making it output some text.